# Is there a better way to model this relationship?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, mode

I have these models:

```
class Assignment(db.Model):
    title = db.StringPeoperty(required=True)
    ...other stuff...

class TeamScore(db.Model):
    assignment = db.ReferenceProperty(Assignment, 
                                      collection_name="teamScores",
                                      required=True)
    teamID = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    score = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    ...other stuff...
```

Here is the peoblem. In the homepage, I want to show the top three( based on score) team work of each assignment. So, I pass this to my template:

```
assignments = Assignment.all()
```

In the template:

```
{% for assignment in assignments%}
    **<!--How to implement showing the top three-->**
    {% for score in assignment.teamScores%}
         {{score.teamID}}
         {{score.score}}
         ...............
    {% endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

With this datastore model. I need to sort in template, it's impossible. So, I think it may have a better model to handle this problem. But I can't figure it out. I thought about this idea that add a ListProperty to store the top three. Everytime a new TeamScore generated, I will compare this to the scores in the List to keep the top three fresh. But I think this way is not elengance.

Can you give me some suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a data modelling issue, it's a templating one. You need to fetch the assignments and perform the queries to get the list of scores in your code, and pass the results into the template, rather than just passing in the assignment model and doing the rest of the work in your template.

Comment: Thanks Nick. But there are many assignments, for each assignment I need the TOP3. If I do query in my python file, it means I need to iterate all these assignments and find everyone's TOP3. You suggest me to put all the TOP3s of each assignment into one score list?I try to user `assignmentEntity.teamScores.order('-score').fetch(3)` to get the TOP3 of one assignment, but it seems the order doesn't work. Order function can't user on reference property, can it?

Comment: @stevenYANG Yes, but you'd have to do that many queries no matter where you do it. I'd suggest constructing a list of (assignment, top-3) tuples, where the second element is a list of top scores.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to make it clear that YES means I can order a refernece property? The code I write in last comment is avaiable?

Comment: @stevenYANG Do you mean "can I order a query that filters on a reference property"? Because that's what your query is doing. And yes, that query is fine - App Engine wouldn't let you execute the query without error if it didn't work.

Comment: Hello, Nick. I do as you said, pass a list of (assignment, top-3) tuples to template. But I encounter some troubles. In template,  `{% for item in list%}` I need to use `item[0]` to find assignment and `item[1]` to find top-3, but template can't  parse []. How can I handle this?

Comment: If you're using Django templates, the syntax is `item.0` and `item.1`.